# If a sequence of absolute values is bounded, does it then converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm stuck on an easy proof. I have a bounded sequence $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|$ and I need to prove that it converges. I don't see how this would work. I don't see how I could use cauchy and also I don't see why this sequence would have to have a limit.

**EDIT**: thanks to the tips the solution was easy. Another proof for the convergence of the sequence $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}$ must be given. Now I cannot use monotonically increasing sequence. I was thinking about rearranging $S_{n}$ in a way that it becomes monotonically increasing but I don't know if that is allowed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The sequence is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Ah, since all the elements are absolutes. And then I can just use the fact that all bounded monotonically increasing functions are convergent, right?

Comment: @Mathbeginner That is correct.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @Mathbeginner You can accept this answer by clicking the check mark on the left side.

Comment: You're right, done.